# youtube Json - C error

Tags: android

I havent got any error but application stopped .
I want to fill in the arraylist from youtube titles.I want to parse Json data from youtube but program is stopped.
How can I fixed this? Where is something wrong?

```
feedUrl="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/muyap/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=2";

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(feedUrl);
HttpResponse responce;
try {
    responce = client.execute(getRequest);
    StatusLine statusLine = responce.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    if(statusCode!=200)
    {

        Toast.makeText(YouTube.this, "Yükleme Gerçekleşmedi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else{
    InputStream JsonStream=responce.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(JsonStream));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
    {

        builder.append(line);
    }
    String JSONdata = builder.toString();
    Log.i("JsonData",JSONdata);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(JSONdata);
    JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONArray items=data.getJSONArray("items");

    for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++)
    {

        JSONObject video=items.getJSONObject(i);
        videoArrayList.add(video.getString("title"));

    }

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(YouTube.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,videoArrayList));

    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

[image: First Log Page]

[image: Second Log Page]

I want to show Log Page 1 and 2.

Comment: Is your `JSONdata` printing in `Log`?

Comment: @Tamilan No , app is stopped when activity running

Comment: There is no error your getting . Nothing printing in log. again run the app if still not getting. try to clean the project and run.

Answer (score 0):

why are using jsonc ...this is new youtube api which does not provide you all the information and tags that you want may be in future. I have used it you should use json format. and this you can also parse it using gson library.

Comment: how can I parse with gson this url ? give me some code please

Answer (score 0):

**Network on UI Thread exception** it is a very common mistake, you shouldn't work with net in the UI thread, use ansytask for it. see my answer here [HttpUrlConnection working on api level < 11, not working on api level >11 on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567613/httpurlconnection-working-on-api-level-11-not-working-on-api-level-11-on-and/20567772#20567772)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**OnCreate()**

```
feedUrl="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/muyap/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=2";

list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
      new JsonParsing(feedUrl).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new String[]{null});
else
    new JsonParsing(feedUrl).execute(new String[]{null});
```

**JsonParsing**

```
 public class JsonParsing extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

            // variables passed in:
            String urls;
            ProgressDialog pDialog;
            //  constructor
            public JsonParsing(String urls) {
                this.urls = urls;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NetActivity.this, "Fetching Details..", "Please wait...", true);
            }


            @Override
            protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(feedUrl);
HttpResponse responce;
try {
    responce = client.execute(getRequest);
    StatusLine statusLine = responce.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    if(statusCode!=200)
    {

        Toast.makeText(YouTube.this, "Yükleme Gerçekleşmedi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else{
    InputStream JsonStream=responce.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(JsonStream));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
    {

        builder.append(line);
    }
    String JSONdata = builder.toString();
    Log.i("JsonData",JSONdata);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(JSONdata);
    JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONArray items=data.getJSONArray("items");

    for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++)
    {

        JSONObject video=items.getJSONObject(i);
        videoArrayList.add(video.getString("title"));

    }
}
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

                return videoArrayList;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
                // Now we have your JSONObject, play around with it.
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                       pDialog.dismiss();

                list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(YouTube.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,result));

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class YouTubeClient {
    // If you are building an Android application that needs to work with all
    // Android
    // SDKs, simply call AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport() and it will decide
    // of
    // these two to use based on the Android SDK level.
    private final HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();

    private final HttpRequestFactory requestFactory;

    private static YouTubeClient youTubeClient;

    public YouTubeClient() {

        requestFactory = transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {

            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
                // headers
                GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
                headers.setApplicationName("YouTubeSample/1.0");
                headers.setGDataVersion("2");
                request.setHeaders(headers);
                request.setParser(new JsonObjectParser(new JacksonFactory()));
            }
        });

    }

    public static YouTubeClient getInstance() {
        if (youTubeClient == null) {
            youTubeClient = new YouTubeClient();
        }

        return youTubeClient;
    }

    public YoutubeGson executeGetFeed(GoogleUrl url) throws VidioException {

//       "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?category=Comedy&time=this_week");
        HttpRequest request;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
            AppLog.i("url-----" + request.getUrl());
            response = request.execute();
        } catch (javax.net.ssl.SSLException e) {
            AppLog.error("entry rejected " + e);
            throw new VidioException(ErrorMessage.REJECTED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
//          Log.i(TAG, "error" + e);
            AppLog.i("error ion execute--1111111--" + e);
            throw new VidioException(ErrorMessage.CONNECTION);
        }
        return getGsonFromFeed(response);

    }

    public YoutubeGson getGsonFromFeed(HttpResponse response) throws VidioException {

        YoutubeGson youtubeGson = null;
        try {
//          AppLog.i("in getfeed------" + response.parseAsString());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            youtubeGson = gson.fromJson(reader, YoutubeGson.class);
//           AppLog.i("----------------------" + youtubeGson.feed.entry);

            // Log.i(TAG, "videoentry   ----" +
//           youtubeGson.feed.entry.get(0).media$group.yt$duration.seconds);

//          AppLog.i("result----------" + youtubeGson.categories.get(0).category_name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
//          Log.i(TAG, "error in get feed---" + e);
            AppLog.i("error in get feed---" + e);
            throw new VidioException(ErrorMessage.GSON);
        }
        return youtubeGson;

    }
```

make pojo classes for responce. nand you are good to go.